# authenticate users against windows AD group using php

Tags: php, active-directory, windows-authentication

i'm developing an app in php that needs only users in a specific win ad group able to login by giving their user name and password.

my environment will be
AD: windows 2008 R2
Web server: IIS7 with PHP 5.x
user group: "testgroup"
domain: testdomain.com

i have gone through several articles and forums, some said pear:auth can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.ldap.html) from the Zend Framework as well (btw you can use it by itself if you want, you don't have to use the complete framework). Examples are given in the docs, you just have to provide the correct parameters and you're off.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i managed to do this with adLDAP
enabled ldap module in php and its working
http://adldap.sourceforge.net/